# Reading from a hidden Mongo Replica set member using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to connect directly to a  delayed hidden secondary member of a Mongo replica set using the default PHP mongo driver. But all attempts have been unsuccessful so far.  I have successfully connected to a non hidden secondary using the same code and config. The only change  being the IP of the two instances. The error I get is given below, but I dont think that it is a valid pointer as  I am able to access the instance via CLI

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with
>   message 'MongoCursor::hasNext(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known

Answer (score 0):

Client applications cannot query a hidden replica set member hence as the drivers would try to reach out to only non-hidden members.